# babel-plugin-module-resolver doesn't work with react native and typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, babeljs, tsconfig

I've been trying to implement module-resolver to my react native app but vs code underlines red the import lines

tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@utils/*": ["./src/utils/*"],
      "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@constants/*": ["./src/constants/*"],
      "@data/*": ["./src/data/*"],
      "@hooks/*": ["./src/hooks/*"],
      "@redux/*:": ["./src/redux/*"],
      "@screens/*": ["./src/screens/*"],
      "@services/*": ["./src/services/*"],
      "@types/*": ["./src/types/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

babel.config.js file

```
 [
            "module-resolver",
            {
              root: ["."],
              extensions: [
                ".ios.ts",
                ".android.ts",
                ".ts",
                ".ios.tsx",
                ".android.tsx",
                ".tsx",
                ".jsx",
                ".js",
                ".json",
              ],
              alias: {
                "@assets": "./assets",
                "@components": "./src/components",
                "@constants": "./src/constants",
                "@data": "./src/data",
                "@hooks": "./src/hooks",
                "@redux": "./src/redux",
                "@screens": "./src/screens",
                "@services": "./src/services",
                "@types": "./src/types",
                "@utils": "./src/utils",
              },
            },
          ],
```

My folder structure is like below

[image]

Error is like this

[image]

Code is working but how can I fix the editor error?

Comment: Did it work?... I'm also facing the same problem mate

Comment: Sorry but I can't remember :/